# Preview button overwrites submit button behavior in form

Tags: javascript, forms, submit

Hope someone can help me out with this problem I am having. I just dont get why my code isnt working properly. :(

I have a simple form with 2 input fields, a preview button and a submit button. The preview button uses this code to send the data to a preview page.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
        <!--
        function formpreview(form) {
        form.target='_blank';
        form.action='preview.php';
        form.submit();
        }
        //-->
</script>
```

This is my form.

```
<form action="create_blog.php" method="post">
    <p><font size="4">Topic</font><br><input type="text" name="topic" size="50" style="height:22px;font-size:1em;" accept-charset="ISO-8859-1"></p>
    <font size="4">Content</font><br><textarea style="resize: none;" name="content" rows="30" cols="100"></textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Preview" onclick='formpreview(this.form)'>
    <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

When I click the Save button first, it works. But if I click the preview first, and then the save button, the save button will work like the preview button instead of saving.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your `formpreview()` function is changing the default action value. You need a function that restores the action value to "create_blog.php".